# extracting a double from the middle of a string, can't use replace

Tags: python, regex, caching

I am trying to test a cache, and I need to extract information from the output.

My code is as follows:

```
import re

for line in open("test-fmath.simout_ruu_size_2"):
    if "avg_alu_power " in line:
        c = line
        print c
        c = re.sub("[^0123456789\.]","",c)
        print c
```

If I do this, my output is:

```
    avg_alu_power               18.9412 # avg power usage of alu

    18.9412
```

Which is correct. But when my input has numbers and periods in it, i.e.:

```
    il1.miss_rate                0.0612 # miss rate (i.e., misses/ref)

    1.0.0612..
```

So I think I need another way to parse it with regex.

Maybe looking for a # and parsing the number or the double before it only? I'm not sure how to do that, though...

Comment: Tried r = r"[0-9\.]*(.*?)#" with findall, doesn't quite work unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be more specific to select only the part you want:

```
>>> re.search(r'([\d.]+)\s+#', text).group(1)
'0.0612'
```

Assuming there's always a "#" char

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex:

```
re.match('.* ([0-9\.]*).*',line).groups()
```